# How to Select option from a drop down which doesn't have options tag in DOM?

Tags: javascript, java, html, selenium

There is a dropdown in an application, when I click on the drop down, I can see the options on the screen, but when I inspect the dropdown, there are no options under selection tag expect the selected option like below

```
<select id="viewMenu" class="fui-select ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-not-empty select2-hidden-accessible" 
ng-model="selectedOption" select-id="viewMenu" name="viewMenu" meta-data="viewMenuMetaData" 
on-select="onItemSelected('viewMenu', item, extraParams)" on-edit="onEditView(item)" 
is-disabled="viewMenuMetaData.disableEdit" id-selection="idSelection" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
<option value="_s3" selected="selected">Documents</option></select>
```

Dropdown screenshot: [image]

I feel that the options are displayed on click of drop down button but I am not able to find the locator for the options.

If anyone has any idea dealing with this, please let me know

Comment: Search in sources for a function called `viewMenu`?

Comment: Write your typical Java code that uses the `Select` class to interact with the SELECT element and then print a count of the options... does it return only one?

Comment: Can you right click on a dropdown option and click inspect?

Comment: @JeffC it return only one

Comment: @Jortega I can't inspect elements, when I right click the drop down closes